# error Debug Assertion Failed - when deleting a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

I've been trying to complete a class assignment but I keep getting an error that I can't seem to resolve. [Debug Assertion failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewIUa.png) I've narrowed the problem (I think) to the destructor. If I comment out the line `delete[] english;` there is no error. I've tried reading through other threads, but they haven't helped solve this. Here are the three files in the project (I took out all the rest of the code because the error still occurs with just this):

Here is the header file:

```
//Dictionaty.h
#ifndef DICTIONARY_H
#define DICTIONARY_H

class Dictionary
{
public:
    Dictionary();
    ~Dictionary();

   void setEnglish(char*);
   char* getEnglish();


private:
    char *english;

};

#endif
```

Here is where the functions are:

```
//dictionary.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Dictionary.h"

using namespace std;

Dictionary::Dictionary()
{
    english = new char[20];


    strcpy(english, " ");
    //strcpy(french, " ");
}

Dictionary::~Dictionary()
{
    delete[] english; // problem is here (i think)

}

void Dictionary::setEnglish(char *eng)
{
    english = eng;
    cout << "the value of english in \"setEnglish()\" is: " << english << endl; //db
}
```

and this is the driver:

```
//dictionaryDrv.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Dictionary.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Dictionary words[30];

    //readIn(words);
    char test[5] = "test";
    words[0].setEnglish(test);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
char test[5] = "test";
words[0].setEnglish(test);
```

Then the member varialbe `english` is assigned to the pointer decayed from array `test`, which isn't dynamic allocated using `new[]` and then can't be `delete[]`ed, but it's exactly what the destructor is trying to do. Therefore UB.

According to the intent of your code, you should use `strcpy` or `strncpy` in `Dictionary::setEnglish`, don't assign the pointer directly.

Other suggestions:

1. Consider about [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), especially when you use raw pointers (such as `char*`).
2. Use [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of C-style strings (`char*`).

Comment: @OP Note that this fix only addresses your current `main` program.  If you change `main` to do something else, such as copy Dictionary objects around, you're going to get into trouble again.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple bugs in the shown code.

```
english = new char;
```

This sets `english` to a dynamically-allocated array of one character, then immediately afterward:

```
strcpy(english, " ");
```

This copies two `char`s - a space and a `\0` - into a buffer of only one character. This runs off at the end of the array, corrupting memory, and results in undefined behavior.

Furthermore, in the destructor:

```
 delete[] english;
```

That, by itself, is fine. Except:

```
void Dictionary::setEnglish(char *eng)
{
    english = eng;
```

As a result of this being called from `main()`, `english` gets set to a pointer to a buffer that was not allocated in dynamic scope. As a result, the destructor will attempt to `delete` something that was not `new`ed. This also results in undefined behavior.

Furthermore, looking ahead, the shown class [violates the Rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), and, as such, it's quite easily to use it incorrectly, resulting in further bugs.

In conclusion, the shown code does not properly handle dynamically-allocated memory, committing several errors along the ones, from overwriting non-allocated memory, to `delete`ing memory that was never `new`ed in the first place.

You need to reread and study the chapter in your C++ book that talks about how to properly use dynamically-allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> `char test[5] = "test";  words[0].setEnglish(test);`
> ```

Here test is allocated in the stack (there is no `new` there). Then `english = eng;` will direct the pointer `english` toward it, you cannot `delete` from the stack.

the fix: since you want your object to *own* the string, you should *copy it*.

```
void Dictionary::setEnglish(char *eng)
{
    delete[] english;
    english = new char[strlen(eng) + 1];
    strcpy(english, eng);
    cout << "the value of english in \"setEnglish()\" is: " << english << endl; //db
}
```

Finally, better use std::string and avoid lot of head-aches.

Comment: that line is actually `english = new char[20];` the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how you set the value inside setEnglish  method, the assigment of **english = eng** don't allocate the value in right way so, It can be fixed if you use strcpy instead:

Use:

```
    void Dictionary::setEnglish(char *eng) {
        strcpy(english,eng);
        cout << "the value of english in \"setEnglish()\" is: " << english << endl; 
}
```

you will get the right behaviour